# Duplicate message delivery to always_bcc with dovecot and Simple Content Filter (Postfix)

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to set up a postfix mail server using

- A Simple content filter (http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter)
- dovecot as a delivery agent.
- `always_bcc` to keep copies of every mail sent.

My relevant configs are:

### master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=filter:dummy
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
filter    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
  flags=Rq user=filter null_sender=
  argv=/var/spool/filter/scripts/filter.sh -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

---

### main.cf (relevant parts only)

```
always_bcc = seccopies@mydomain.example
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

---

### /var/spool/filter/scripts/filter.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/cat | /var/spool/filter/scripts/mailfilter | /usr/sbin/sendmail -G -i "$@"

exit $?
```

---

- All my users have emails in "(Initial).surname@mydomain.example" format
- There are security groups that act as roles and each one have emails in "role@mydomain.example" format.
- Basically, a role email function as an alias to several users.
- I can set permissions using groups/roles, not users (the whole point of this)

For example

- my user email is y.hernandez@mydomain.example
- I'm a member of role I.T.Department (informatics@mydomain.example)
- I'm a member of some other roles, but my main role is "I.T.Department"
- Because I'm a member of this group/role I have certain privileges, as the other members.
- Every mail sent to informatics@mydomain.example will reach me and the other members.

So far, so good... But my boss want that every mail I send use the informatics@mydomain.example (role) address instead of y.hernandez@mydomain.example (user). i.e. that every mail sent use the principal role email, not the user email.

`/var/spool/filter/scripts/mailfilter` is an in-house made filter that just does that (changes "from" addresses from "(Initial).surname@" to "role@" checking an LDAP server).

It never fails (In case of any error condition, it just copies standard input into standard output and no modification is made, so no address change).

The problem is, when I send an email, it delivers two copies to seccopies@mydomain.example as seen in the logs, not one copy as expected.

---

```
Dec 16 16:23:08 correo2 postfix/smtpd[32453]: connect from informatica1.mydomain.example[10.128.159.15]
Dec 16 16:23:08 correo2 postfix/smtpd[32453]: DD925380C87: client=informatica1.mydomain.example[10.128.159.15], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=y.hernandez@mydomain.example
Dec 16 16:23:08 correo2 postfix/cleanup[32456]: DD925380C87: message-id=<002401d91194$982edba0$c88c92e0$@mydomain.example>
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/qmgr[32275]: DD925380C87: from=<y.hernandez@mydomain.example>, size=2749, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/pickup[32274]: AAFEF380C8D: uid=110 from=<y.hernandez@mydomain.example>
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/pipe[32457]: DD925380C87: to=<seccopies@mydomain.example>, relay=filter, delay=0.81, delays=0.11/0/0/0.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via filter service)
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/pipe[32457]: DD925380C87: to=<y.hernandez@mydomain.example>, orig_to=<informatics@mydomain.example>, relay=filter, delay=0.81, delays=0.11/0/0/0.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via filter service)
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/qmgr[32275]: DD925380C87: removed
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/cleanup[32456]: AAFEF380C8D: message-id=<002401d91194$982edba0$c88c92e0$@mydomain.example>
Dec 16 16:23:09 correo2 postfix/qmgr[32275]: AAFEF380C8D: from=<y.hernandez@mydomain.example>, size=2927, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 dovecot: lda(seccopies@mydomain.example)<32488><2DSfML3hnGPofgAA0V72BQ>: msgid=<002401d91194$982edba0$c88c92e0$@mydomain.example>: saved mail to INBOX
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 postfix/pipe[32473]: AAFEF380C8D: to=<seccopies@mydomain.example>, relay=dovecot, delay=1.1, delays=0.79/0/0/0.28, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 dovecot: lda(seccopies@mydomain.example)<32490><Au2fML3hnGPqfgAA0V72BQ>: msgid=<002401d91194$982edba0$c88c92e0$@mydomain.example>: saved mail to INBOX
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 postfix/pipe[32471]: AAFEF380C8D: to=<seccopies@mydomain.example>, relay=dovecot, delay=1.1, delays=0.79/0/0/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 dovecot: lda(y.hernandez@mydomain.example)<32489><BE2gML3hnGPpfgAA0V72BQ>: msgid=<002401d91194$982edba0$c88c92e0$@mydomain.example>: saved mail to INBOX
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 postfix/pipe[32470]: AAFEF380C8D: to=<y.hernandez@mydomain.example>, relay=dovecot, delay=1.1, delays=0.79/0/0/0.35, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Dec 16 16:23:10 correo2 postfix/qmgr[32275]: AAFEF380C8D: removed
Dec 16 16:23:11 correo2 postfix/smtpd[32453]: disconnect from informatica1.mydomain.example[10.128.159.15] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
```

---

uid=110 is "filter" user uid. "From" is only changed in the headers, inside of the email, so it doesn't show on the logs.

Everything is running as it should be except this double delivery detail.

Any idea of how can I fix it?

Comment: You could ask here instead https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I did ask there. No answer so far. Thanks